# App:Post object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation using symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have post by id or by slug, use ParamConverter but I find App error: `Post object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation`.knowing that I am a beginner at symfony and I followed a training.

I tried the route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post/1`

**BlogController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\Post;
/**
 * @Route("/blog")
*/
class BlogController extends AbstractController {

    /**
    * @Route("/post/{id}", requirements={ "id" : "\d+" }, name="get_one_post_by_id", methods={"GET"})
    * @ParamConverter("post", class="App:Post")
    */
    public function postById($post){
        return $this->json($post);
    }
    /**
    * @Route("/post/{slug}", methods={"GET"})
    * @ParamConverter("post", class="App:Post", options={"mapping": {"slug": "slug"}})
    */
    public function postBySlug($post){
        return $this->json($post);  
    }
    /**
    * @Route("/post/{id}", name="delete-post", methods={"DELETE"})
    */
    public function destroy(Post $post){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($post);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->json(null, 204);
    }
```

Comment: add the object as parameter  `public function postBySlug(Post $post)`

Answer (score 1):

it should looks like:

```php
use App\Entity\Post;

    /**
    * @Route("/post/{id}", requirements={ "id" : "\d+" }, name="get_one_post_by_id", methods={"GET"})
    */
    public function postById(Post $post){
        return $this->json($post);
    }
```

that's all